# Haskell : How do I reverse a the children of a Tree recursive

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I am trying to reverse the children of a Tree in haskell. The Tree looks like this:

```
data Tree v e = Node v [(e,Tree v e)]
```

At the moment I do it with these two functions:

```
rev :: Tree v e -> Tree v e
rev (Node v []) = Node v []
rev (Node v xs) =
  let xs' = (rev'(snd (unzip xs)))
  in Node v (zip (fst (unzip xs)) (map rev xs'))


rev' :: [Tree v e] -> [Tree v e]
rev' [] = []
rev' (x:xs) = (rev' xs) ++ [x]
```

I am not even sure if this works 100%. Is there any way to do it recursive in just one function? I feel like my way is inefficient. I was trying to write a function that looks like this:

```
revRec :: Tree v e -> Tree v e
revRec (Node v [])     = Node v []
revRec (Node v (x:xs)) = Node v (revRec xs ++ [x])
```

Obviosuly I can't call `revRec` with `xs` since `xs` a list. I just can't wrap my head around this problem even though I feel like it shoudn't be that hard.

Comment: Firstly, you don't even need the `rev (Node v []) = .. ` case, the general list cases cover the empty list case as well. Secondly, using `unzip` seems perfectly reasonable - the use of `fst` and `snd` (also multiple calls to `unzip`) should probably be eliminated. You can write it with primitive recursion by eg. `rev (Node a ts) = Node a $ uncurry (\x y -> zip x (y [])) $ foldr (\(e,t) (as, bs) -> (e:as, bs . (rev t :))) ([], id) ts`. But I really doubt this is more efficient than the `unzip/reverse` version (and it's certainly uglier).

Answer (score 2):

**Zeroth**, clean up your code. You don't need those many parens, and you should avoid duplicate computations. `fst` and `snd` on twice the same thing? Meh. Better use pattern matching:

```
rev :: Tree v e -> Tree v e
rev (Node v xs)
  = let (es, cs) = unzip xs
        xs' = rev' cs
    in Node v $ zip es (map rev xs')

rev' :: [Tree v e] -> [Tree v e]
rev' [] = []
rev' (x:xs) = rev' xs ++ [x]
```

**First** note that `rev'` is not specific to lists of trees, at all! It's just <sup><sub>an inefficient implementation of</sub></sup> the standard [`reverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:reverse) function, which works on any list.

**Second**, this unzipping/zipping is a bit clumsy. Are you sure this is actually the behaviour you want: right now you're only reversing the list of children, but the order of *elements* stays the same. If not, then you'd better do it all with one reverse and one map:

```
rev :: Tree v e -> Tree v e
rev (Node v xs) = Node v . reverse $ map (\(e,c) -> (e, rev c)) xs
```

or, even nicer,

```
import Control.Arrow

rev (Node v xs) = Node v . reverse $ map (second rev) xs
```

Comment: A picky efficiency point: for Good Reasons (really, I promise), `reverse` doesn't participate in list fusion. Therefore, `reverse . map f` should ideally be fused by hand into an application of `mapReverse` (a name I made up, with the obvious sense).

Comment: A picky didactic point: the `Arrow` abstraction is intimidating to even intermediate-level Haskellers like myself. Therefore, I strongly recommend using the `second` from `Data.Bifunctor` instead. `Bifunctor` is, IMO, a much more beginner-friendly abstraction.

Comment: what about just using the Functor instance for `(,)`? it is the same as `second` if I remember correctly.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, it's *not* actually the same, because the `Functor` instance is strictly law-abiding (hence probably better here) while the `Bifunctor` instance is only morally so. So you're probably right that `fmap` is better. That said, there's a case to be made for `(,)` being a more intuitive `Bifunctor` than `(a,)` is a functor.

Comment: @dfeuer I disagree, arrows are an excellent abstraction IMO. (They're tricky – and needless – as monad substitutes, but I don't see what's hard to understand about the `Arrow` class as such – you know, _it's just a well-pointed monoidal category, what's the problem_...) Wheras @epsilonhalbe the functor instances of `(a,)` and `a->` are, well... I'm not a fan of these. Really, `(,)` is the canonical example of a bifunctor, and looking at “half this bifunctor” is quite a lop-sided perspective.

Comment: Now that we have mentioned `Bifunctor` we should say what it is: it is just something that has two types and is a functor in every one separatedly, think of Pairs, Eithers ...

Comment: how can i write the same function for `data Tree t = Node t [Tree t]`

Comment: i found it  : ```reverseT (Node t []) = Node t []  \n
reverseT (Node t (x:xs)) =  Node t $ (map reverseT xs) ++ [reverseT x]```